# How do I enter Meditation Mode?

Tags: the-witcher-2

The game is telling me that in order to drink potions, I must enter Meditation Mode, but it doesn't give me any clue how to enter Meditation Mode in the first place.  How do I do that?

Comment: Are you Xbox or PC?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Meditation option is in the center of the radial menu, which is accessed through <kbd>left-Ctrl</kbd>. This is also where you can select magic for quick cast and your melee weapon.

If you are playing on Xbox, hold down "Select"/"Back Button" and press A.

[image]

Comment: This wouldn't work if the person was on Xbox, as he hasn't stated that he is or isn't, it's a good thing to include both, I sent you a edit with that. Up to you to accept it or not.

Comment: @Wojtek You are correct, it's good to include both. (It wasn't included originally, because when the question and answer were posted, the game was PC-only).

Comment: Ahh, I thought this was a new question, damn that's an old question. I wonder did the guy quit the game cause he never got an answer :L